# N1QL document containing list of objects query

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am fairly new to N1QL queries. I have some documents like this.

```
[
  {
     "id":"id_1",
     "data":{
        "name":"name_1"
     },
     "type":"type_1"
  },
  {
     "id":"id_2",
     "data":{
        "name":"name_2"
     },
     "type":"type_2"
  },
  {
     "id":"id_3",
     "data":{
        "name":"name_3"
     },
     "type":"type_3"
  }
]
```

what index should i create to be able to get all the documents that have the `"type"="type_3"` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an index like the one below to index all the documents of type type_3.

`` create index idx_type_3 on `bucket_name`.scope.collection(data) where type="type_3" ``